# application page caching

Tags: .net, iis, caching

I'd like to cache a particular page at application level.

What is the the simplest way of doing this?

I tried caching on IIS 7, as per this article but it didn't seem to work:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/154/walkthrough-iis-70-output-caching/

Thanks

Comment: what did you try? why did not work?

Comment: I just edited the question to show the method I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put this on top of the aspx page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None"%>
```

Source: [How to: Set the Cacheability of an ASP.NET Page Declaratively](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1ysf1y.aspx)